# How to set docker run option in jelastic, especialy the max file descriptors (ulimit)

Tags: docker, jelastic

I'm trying to install elasticsearch on jelastic using the [official documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/elasticsearch)

Eventually there is an error when starting the container:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed 
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
```

I tried a number of possibilities to set the ulimit but none are working.

What's the best way to set this?

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found a way by editing the file `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` and adding near the start the following:

```
ulimit -n 65536
```

Is this the best approach?

Comment: Another option was to bring  your own /etc/security/limits.conf file with the image where this limit is already edited. Personally I prefer more the way you did by changing contents of the entry point script so the limit will be related only to that particular process.